# What happened to Nobanion between 4e and 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, lore, forgotten-realms, religions-and-deities

The deity [Nobanion](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Nobanion) has a Forgotten Realms wiki article for 2e, 3e and 4e, but not 5e.

Does the absence of a 5e article indicate that he canonically does not exist during the time/events/context of 5e?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### He just hasn't appeared in a 5e sourcebook yet.

Nobanion is mentioned in *Elminster's Forgotten Realms* (2012), a 4e-era product in which he is alive and well.

He's mentioned in [The Reaver](https://books.google.com/books?id=uVpVAQAAQBAJ) (2014), which according to the Forgotten Realms wiki takes place in [1486 DR](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/1486_DR). Since the wiki states that the 5th edition adventure module The Rise of Tiamat takes place in the 1480s DR, we can be reasonably certain that Nobanion is still alive and well as of D&D 5th edition. We just haven't seen him in a 5th edition D&D sourcebook because relatively few Forgotten Realms sourcebooks have been released for D&D 5th edition.

The wiki page for 1385 DR and 1486 DR summarizes what happened to Nobanion as described by the novel *The Reaver*. In 1385 DR:

> Nobanion tried to save a pride of lions in Gulthandor from oncoming blue fire. He came in contact with the blue fire, and it mutated him into a dark and bestial lion with a mane of blue flame.

And in 1486 DR:

> Nobanion, still under Malar's control, is tasked to capture Stedd Whitehorn, the boy Chosen of Lathander, but Stedd and his companions heal him of his corruption by blue fire. He returns to his natural state, and introduces himself to Stedd and his companions; in his reinstated form, he is no longer under Malar's control. He guides the young Chosen through the wilds of Gulthandor, parting ways just before Stedd and company enter Turmish.

Comment: The Reaver is part of the Sundering series, the in-universe account of events marking the transition between 4e and 5e. So it is the best possible answer to OPs question: "What happened to Nobanion between 4e and 5e?"